# PhantomJS can't find jasmine fixture

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs

In Jasmine I am adding a fixture as below:

```
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = '/';

var fixture = readFixtures('test2.html');
setFixtures(fixture);
```

The tests run fine in the browser.

However, when I try to run the tests using PhantomJS I get the following error:

```
Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(ContentNotFoundError) ( "Error opening /test2.html: No such file or directory" ) URL: "file:///test2.html?_=123456789
```

It's as if PhantomJS cannot read the correct relative file path.

Is there anything I can do differently to get past this error?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this, the trick is to call the actual url as opposed to a file, so instead of

```
$ phantomjs myTest.js path/to/my/SpecRunner.html
```

try:

```
$ phantomjs myTest.js http://localhost/path/to/mySpecRunner.html
```